# Rails 4 - Multiple apps using centralized database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose we have this scenario:

- www.main.com - Main interface where admin (foo, bar, etc..) can store products, based on their own e-commerce
- www.foo.com - Sample store that sells items from the "foo" store
- www.bar.com - Sample store that sells items from the "bar" store

The problem is finding a way to centralize the database structure and models.

I prefer to keep every single store in separated apps (so I exclude rails engines).

For instance, if a user buys something in the "foo" store, I need to interact with the main db and update it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not really sure I understand... So you have many DBs ? One for each app + a "main db" used by several apps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails works much better with a "one database, one app" model. There are lots of ways how you can share models across apps (gems, engines, git submodules, etc), but none of those ways is great. You end up introducing lots of overhead in your development, deployment, and testing process. You also invite lots of hidden dependencies between code, as Rails doesn't give you easy way to keep clean abstraction (for example, you wrote a helper for store Foo, and then your coworker used that helper in store Bar, and then every time you change Foo, Bar breaks).

I recommend a centralized API approach instead:

1. api.foobarmain.com - a app/service that provides RESTful API for all the functionality of all stores.

   - This app has all the db models, and it exposes them as resources in the API for other apps to interact with.
   - This app can have an admin UI for all the stores, if you need it. Alternatively, admin UI may be another client of an API.
2. www.foo.com - a full stack app that interacts with API at api.foobarmail.com

   - There is no shared database connection to API, everything that you need to interact has to be exposed via API.
   - There will be no shared code between www.foo.com and www.bar.com. Code reuse happens only by virtue of using the same API app/service.
   - From the perspective of www.foo.com, the model layer (in MVC) is powered by API, not by database.
   - You can still have its own database on www.foo.com if you need to store data specific to www.foo.com only.
3. www.bar.com - another full stack app that interacts with API
4. so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using multiple schema if you are using Postgresql. I have a similar issue with a new project that I about to start.

You can use `gem 'apartment'` to deal with different schemas. The queries will be a bit complicated but with different schemas you will end up with one database and you can create different namespaces to respond accordingly.

You can set up so app select the correct schema based on the Domain or Subdomain.

Here is the link: https://github.com/influitive/apartment